# Profile in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, memory-leaks, profiler

I need to investigate a memory leak in my microservice. I see some `Profile...` menu item in Intellij

[image]

After I click it application is run. Could you tell me where I can see the results of profiling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This action is for profiling Android apps and is provided by the Android plug-in. The feature is [described in Android Studio documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler).

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't have Java profiling out of the box at the moment. You can use third-party profilers like JProfiler or jvisualvm.

Answer (score 0):

In Intellij Ultimate 2018.3 there is an experimental feature for profiling that can be [activated for Linux or MacOSX](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/09/intellij-idea-2018-3-eap-git-submodules-jvm-profiler-macos-and-linux-and-more/). It makes use of the [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) and which can monitor java heap allocations which might point to a memory leak.

Unfortunately it doesn't yet support Maven or Gradle projects.